# div flex box selection by click and drag

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have multiple flexboxes and I would like to select box by click and drag.

eg.

I want to select 1 to 6, just click 1 and drag to 6. So all selected div will back background color change to blue or something and I would like to get selected box data like id or other information.

How can I achieve this? Just want to know is there any way to select the flexbox by click and drag.

I don't have any code for this yet. I am thinking I need to do this by mouse enter, mouse down, and mouse up event? or can be done by CSS for selection? using table cell is better for this selection?

[image]

Comment: @NicoShultz, Is there any way to use it without jquery?

Comment: You'd have to roll your own handlers. Trap mouse button clicks and drags. The Jquery UI is really easy to use for drag and drop, just a few lines of code. Way easier than starting from scratch.

Comment: Offcourse you can build it from scratch in js or use another framework

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [ngx-drag-to-select](https://d3lm.github.io/ngx-drag-to-select/) to achieve what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Angular Material's [drag and drop CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview).

Comment: It's not like drag and drop. Imagine like excel. If u want to select multiple cell, u just click and drag to select right? I would like to do the same logic with the flex box(div).